# Select latest message of each conversation

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, chat

I've two tables:

**chat** (`from` is just who have sent the first message)

```
id | id_from | id_to
1  | 1       | 2
2  | 1       | 3
3  | 3       | 2
4  | 4       | 1
```

**message**

```
id | content | date                | id_chat | id_from | id_to
1  | hi      | 2017-10-04 23:14:41 | 1       | 1       | 2
2  | hello   | 2017-10-04 23:15:03 | 1       | 2       | 1
3  | heey    | 2017-10-04 23:40:00 | 4       | 4       | 1
```

And I want to get last message of each conversation.

I tried (`1` is the user logged id):

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS idMessage, id_from, id_to, content, date 
FROM message 
WHERE 1 IN (id_from, id_to) 
GROUP BY id_chat
ORDER BY idMessage 
DESC LIMIT 10
```

I'm getting the latest conversations, but I get the first message of each conversation, not the last one. How can I get the last message?

Comment: i did not understand latest mean last message i think , can clearly explain what you want.

Comment: @AmiteshKumar Exactly, means last message. With the query above, I'm getting, for example, the message with content "hi" instead of "hello" (last record) for id_chat = 1

Comment: You could select the max(date) group by chat id. Then join with the table chat to get the extra attributes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select m1.*
from messages m1
join
(
  SELECT MAX(id) as id
  FROM message
  GROUP BY id_chat
) m2 on m1.id = m2.id
```

Comment: It working! I just added `WHERE 1 IN (id_from, id_to)` before `GROUP BY` on subquery (otherwise the code would get the latest messages from all users, not just the logged in user) and `ORDER BY id DESC` at the end of subquery.

Comment: To get just one last message you can do it much simpler: `SELECT * 
FROM message 
WHERE 1 IN (id_from, id_to)
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT m.content as idMessage, m.id_from, m.id_to, m.date  from message as m JOIN chat c WHERE <Logged_ID> = m.id_chat ORDER BY m.date DESC LIMIT 1
```